# How to code "Category" for tumblr

Tags: tumblr

christinerenu.tumblr.com

I have managed to get a theme that allows for Categories.

I was wondering on how to tag/code my posts to display on each "Category" page.

eg: I was would like the coffee related images to display when I click on "Cafe"

Cheers

Comment: Can't you simply change Cafe's link to _christinerenu.tumblr.com/tagged/coffee/_ instead of _christinerenu.tumblr.com/tagged/cafe_ ?

Comment: Yes, Thanks! Sorry Im very new to learning all this :)

Comment: Haha it's alright, good luck.

Comment: @WalkerChristie post your comment as an answer, handy for other users with the same issue as the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to change

*christinerenu.tumblr.com/tagged/cafe/*
to *christinerenu.tumblr.com/tagged/coffee*

You can do this by going to your blog's "customize" tab, and editing the HTML.  Try searching the code by pressing **Ctrl-F** on your keyboard, this will allow you to search.  Search for "cafe" until you find the link.  Simply change "/tagged/cafe" with "/tagged/coffee"